# Kendo DataSource.filter(date) causes application to crash

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik-appbuilder, everlive

I'm trying to filter some data for a chart with date-sensitive information

if I select a date range, with no date, that would return an empty array of results, the application doesn't crash, but as soon as there is data withing the range of the FilterDate and gte (hence, there are points made after the filterDate), then the application crashes on that line.

```
axisChange : function(){
  //set date from period
  var filterDate = new Date();

  switch(this.get('selectedPeriod'))
  {
    case 'week':
      filterDate.setMonth(filterDate.getMonth()-1);
      break;
    case 'day':
      filterDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate()-7);
      break;
    case 'hour':
      filterDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate()-1);
      break;
  }
  /*var chart = jQuery("#chart").data("kendoChart");
  chart.setOptions({ categoryAxis: { baseUnit: this.get('selectedCategory') }});*/
  dataSource.filter({
    "field": "CreatedAt",
    "operator": "gt",
    "value": filterDate
  });
}
```

EDIT

ON closer inspection this is an issue with dataSource.filter, specific to the date, if I try to use another filter like:

```
dataSource.filter({
                        "field": "Note",
                        "operator": "contains",
                        "value": 'e'
                    });
```

everything is updated okay according to the filter.

**FOR DETAILED CODE, PLEASE VISIT GITHUB REPO**

https://github.com/Danelund/NeuroHelper/blob/master/NeuroHelper/scripts/app.js

Comment: any error message on console?

Comment: @DionDirza - that's the problem, it just completely freezes

Comment: What version of kendo are you using? I had tried with Kendo 2015 Q1 SP1 in my local and works perfectly. It's better for you to create some mirror site that reproduce this error, so we can help you furthermore..

Comment: I suggest you to reassure of your `DataSource` if `CreatedAt` property is really type of date..

Answer (score 0):

My first thought about this problem is about date format. Place a breakpoint before `dataSource.filter` line and check what is the date format. Probably you should also convert this date object to string using some kind of `date.toString()` function.

```
dataSource.filter({
  "field": "CreatedAt",
  "operator": "gt",
  "value": filterDate.toString()
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I actually changed the format to just the Date object, and removed the toString, as I thought that might be a problem aswell, but unfortunately that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you specified the type of the field that you want to filter (i.e. CreatedAt) to be of type "date" ?
How to do so is demonstrated [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model).

```
schema: {
model: {
  id: "ProductID",
  fields: {
    CreatedAt: {
      type: "date"
    },
```